# What exactly should I test when calling React's this.props.onClick(this) in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I've been writing tests for all my events (and everything else of course) but I'm at a loss on how to test that this.props.onClick(this) was called on a child component.

My child component has the following code:

```
closeModal: function() {
  this.props.onClick(this);
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <i className="close-icon" onClick={this.closeModal}></i>
  )
}
```

and the parent is listening to it like so:

```
onCloseModal: function() {
  this.replaceState({
    modalStatus: 'hidden'
  });
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <QuestionModal modalStatus={this.state.modalStatus} onClick={this.onCloseModal} />
  )
}
```

I know how to test the parent's click event and I know how to call the child's button click event in the tests as well but I'm not sure what I should be exactly testing.

If I used Sinon and Jasmine, I would stub the closeModal method and check that it was called. Can I do that with Jest and if so how exactly?

**UPDATE**

I've tried writing a test based on @PhilVarg's answer but I'm not getting very far as I'm not able to mock *closeModal*.

Here's my test:

```
      var closeIcon,
          myMock = jest.genMockFunction();

      form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <QuestionForm />
      );
      form.closeModal = myMock;

      closeIcon = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(form, 'close-icon');

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIcon);

      expect(form.closeModal).toBeCalled();
```

The test errors with *Expected Function to be called.* and closeModal is not mocked but still runs (I have a console log in it at the moment). I've been on it all afternoon but haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I would just check that the state is replaced.

Comment: Yeah I am checking that on the parent component but I also want to test that the click on the child component does what it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to some of the suggestions from Phil, I finally figured it out. What I want to test is that closeModal is called when I click the icon. I have already tested that the parent component behaves as expected but I couldn't work out how to mock closeModal because I'm testing this specific component and by default, this is the only one Jest doesn't mock for me. I could stub it manually but that somehow didn't want to work.

What I've done now is mock this.props.onClick within closeModal and I check that it fires.

Here's how that looks in code:

```
describe('QuestionForm', function() {
  var onClickFunc,
      form;

  beforeEach(function() {
    onClickFunc = jest.genMockFunction();

    form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <QuestionForm onClick={onClickFunc} />
    );
  });

  it('should call closeModal when the icon is clicked', function() {
    var closeIcon = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(form, 'close-icon');

    TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIcon);

    expect(onClickFunc).toBeCalled();
  });

});
```

I think that sufficiently tests that closeModal behaves as expected.

Comment: I'm new to React and Jest and was having similar trouble with how to mock an event-driven function.  This helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the function is called you'd want to use jest's [`toBeCalled`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html#custom-matchers) function (or `toBeCalledWith`). Assuming you've done some set up to instantiate the components, renderIntoDocument, and simulate the click (checkout [the tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) if not)

```
describe('#closeModal', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    // setup in here to instantiate / render component 
    // and simulate the click if the i tag
  })
  it('is called on click', function(){
    expect(questionModal.closeModal).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

EDIT:
Ok, so after tinkering with it, I was able to get a passing test doing something similar to your original structure. I created a mock function, but instead of doing form.closeModal = mock, I passed the mock into the Question as the onClick prop, and checked if it got called.

```
describe('#closeModal', function(){
  var mock, form, closeIcon;

  beforeEach(function(){
    mock = jest.genMockFunction();
    form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <QuestionForm onClick={ mock } />
    );
    closeIcon = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(form, 'close-icon');
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIcon);
  })

  it('is called on click', function(){
    expect(mock).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: That errors because toBeCalled() only works on mocks but closeModal is not mocked. I have not been able to figure out how it can be mocked.

Comment: if you dont want to mock the entire component you can try to mock the `#closeModal` function in the `beforeEach` directly using `questionModal.closeModal = jest.genMockFunction()` instead of of setting it to myMock. This scenario is where the flux architecture shines. since you'd be using an action object to send the message to replace state which will be mocked by default.

Comment: Also, if youre testing form (not questionModal) I think you should be mocking  `onCloseModal`, not `closeModal`

Comment: I want to test that closeModal on the child component (the form) is called. I have a passing test for onCloseModal in the parent component (the modal). I added this test `form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <QuestionForm />
      );

      form.closeModal = jest.genMockFunction();

      var closeIcon = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(form, 'fa-times');

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIcon);

      expect(form.closeModal).toBeCalled();` and it errors because onClick is not defined.

Comment: So I modified it and added this to the test `function doSomething() {
        console.log('test runs');
      }

      form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <QuestionForm onClick={doSomething} />
      );` and now the test fails because `Expected Function to be called.`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asynchronous test. You have to call `done()` in your `onClick` handler. If everything is fine the handler will call `done()` and the test passes. If the handler won't be called the test fails after some time because Jasmine cannot end it.

No need for stubbing or mocking.

```
it('should click', function(done) {
  function onClick() {
    done();
  }
  var instance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Component onClick={onClick} />
  );
  var button = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(instance, 'button');
  var buttonDOM = React.findDOMNode(button);
  React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.click(buttonDOM);
});
```

Comment: That errors with `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line where I call done() in the onClick function.

Comment: Did you put `done` into your function as an argument, like so `function(done)` ?

Comment: Yes I did. My function looks like this: `it('should call closeModal when the icon is clicked', function(done) {
      function doSomething() {
        done();
      }
      
      form = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <QuestionForm onClick={doSomething} />
      );
      
      var closeIcon = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(form, 'close-icon'),
          closeIconDOM = React.findDOMNode(closeIcon); 

      TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIcon);
      
      expect(form.closeModal).toBeCalled();
    });`

Comment: You don't need the last line `expect(...)`.

Comment: But if I don't have an expect, then I'm not testing anything...? I'm just setting up the test and then I'm clicking the icon and then I'm not testing for anything that should happen after the click. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're testing that the function was called by putting the `done()` inside it. If the function is not called the test will fail.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I removed the expect from the test I posted a few comments back and changed the last line to `TestUtils.Simulate.click(closeIconDOM);` and I still get `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on the line where the done is passed into the it statement. Any idea why?